# Django: Filter over several relationships

Tags: django

I have publications with a list of scanned pages and words on it. The relationships are like this:

```
# models.py
class Publication(models.Model):
    pass

class Page(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey('Publication')

class Link(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey('Page')

class Word(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey('Link')
```

Now, I have the id of one word. How do I get every publication that contains that word? Also, when given one id of a publication, how do I get a list of all the words in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this configuration, a `Word` can have only one `Publication` so the below query set will give you a single `Publication` no matter what as your models are connected with `ForeignKey` from bottom to top instead of `ManyToManyField`:

```
Publication.objects.filter(page_set__link__set__word__id=word_id)
```

similarly, this will give you the same publication as a single object:

```
Word.objects.get(pk=word_id).link.page.publication
```

If you want to get all words in a publication:

```
Word.objects.filter(link__page__publication__id=publication_id)
```